# Granting site permissions to AD security group

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I need to grant permissions to a large group of people (over 1000) so adding each user is not practical. I created an active directory security group and added mailing lists containing those users to it then granted permissions to that security group. However people under the security group are still blocked from the site. There is nothing in the logs. What's missing?

Answer (score 2):

If your AD group doesn't contain other security groups with the users in, they won't be visible to SharePoint. It can't see Distribution groups.

Comment: The users I need to add aren't in security groups. They're all in a huge hierarchy of distribution groups. The parent distribution group was added to the security group. Some of the users do get access and some don't so I don't know what SharePoint is doing.

Comment: Please use the "Check Permissions" button on the "/_layouts/user.aspx" page to compare an user that gets access with someone that do not.

Comment: Sharepoint doesn't handle distribution groups as James said, it will only handle flat security groups, meaning if there's any nesting, the users won't be picked up.